# vbscript : Type Incompatible on Sub call

Tags: vba, vbscript, byref, coreldraw

I wrote a vbscript based on a vba code I had written in which an object's method expects some Double to be passed ByRef. In vba this works very fine, while in vbscript I've got "Type Icnompatible" error.

```
<package>
    <job id="Main">
       <reference object="CorelDraw.Application" version="16.0" />
        <script language="VBScript">
            Option Explicit
            Dim app
            Dim doc
            Dim pg
            Set app = GetObject(, "CorelDraw.Application.16")
            set doc = app.ActiveDocument
            Set pg = doc.pages.Item(1)


            Dim h0, w0
            'h0=0
            'w0=0 
            h0=cdbl(0) 'Trying to force Variant to Double
            w0=cdbl(0) 

            call pg.GetSize(w0, h0)

            Wscript.echo "h orig=" + CStr(h0) + ",w orig=" + CStr(w0) + " unit=" + CStr(doc.Unit)

        </script>
    </job>
</package>
```

I receive a "`Type incompatible: 'GetSize'`" error.

Working vba code is

```
Sub test()

    Dim doc As Document
    Dim pg As page
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    Dim h0 As Double, w0 As Double

    Set pg = doc.Pages.Item(1)
    pg.GetSize w0, h0


    Debug.Print "h orig=" + CStr(h0) + ",w orig=" + CStr(w0) + " unit=" + CStr(doc.Unit)

End Sub
```

Any idea how to solve this ?

Regards,

Comment: did you try currency type?

Comment: I think VBScript has only Variant variables, so you cannot pass a Double variable by reference because you would always end up with a Variant holding a double value, which is not what the callee is expecting.

Comment: @Zam: I just tried. Same result.

Comment: @TheBlastOne : you're right. But is there a solution to that ?

Comment: You´d need to create an intermediate layer which is callable from VBScript, converts the variants to doubles, and calls the target API that accepts doubles. The easiest way to achieve this would be to create a VB component for that, or a C DLL. (Delphi is too exotic meanwhile to be recommended, but authoring a DLL there would be super-easy.)

Comment: "The easiest way to achieve this would be to create a VB component for that, or a C DLL. (Delphi is too exotic meanwhile to be recommended, but authoring a DLL there would be super-easy.)" This is far too complicated for me !!! I'm not familiar with VB, nor Delphi, nor C. And my latest attempts to build dll's has been wasted time. I wrote this vbscript to manipulate CorelDraw files from within Java....